# CreateFile() returns error 32 (SHARING_VIOLATION) when connecting to a named pipe

Tags: vb6, named-pipes, createfile

I've really been struggling with VB6 named pipes for a while.
This line to a large extend works:

```
CallNamedPipe(szPipeName, Header(0), 2, bArray(0), numBytes, cbRead, 30000)
```

The pipe server does receive the 2 bytes written. However this function is not what I want to use. I need to use the CreateFile() + WriteFile() combination. Now I cannot get this one working:

```
pipeHandle = CreateFile(szPipeName, GENERIC_READ Or GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0&)
```

It returns -1, meaning it failed. Nothing else is changed so I don't understand why it fails.
Then I tried it on an existing file C:\test.txt:

```
pipeHandle = CreateFile("C:\\test.txt", GENERIC_READ Or GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0&)
```

It still failed and returned -1.

Am I using CreateFile() wrong?

Comment: The error code returned is 32 i.e ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION. But I'm not using the FILE_SHARE_READ and FILE_SHARE_WRITE flags. Just now I tried adding those flags, but it still gave me error code 32.

Comment: Looks ok.  The one with a disk file name is probably failing with error 2 (file not found).  The Named Pipe one is probably failing because the server is oversubscribed (max instances exceeded) or has no pending Connect hanging.

Comment: @Bob, I'm still stuck. The disk file really exists, but CreateFile() really returns -1 with error code 32. And the named pipe really is listening. My C++ and C# client happily connect and talk to it any time. This is mysterious.

Answer (score 0):

Problem all solved. 
It was a Unicode/ANSI problem. The file/pipe name string is not parsed correctly. Use CreateFileA instead.